# Persistent error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, syntax, directory, path, oserror

I have:

```
log_dir = Path('C:/Users/Rose/project/log/')
```

But I am getting:

The system cannot find the path specified: "'\Users\Rose\project\log'"

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "'C:\\Users\\Rose\\project\\log'"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Have you verified that the path exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Comment: what is the line of code that the error actually comes from?

Comment: Are you using Python for Windows or WSL Python?

Comment: The path syntax is what's wrong. Look at the single quotes within double quotes. The code you've shown is not the runtime code. Note also the lack of a drive letter *"'\Users\Rose\project\log'"*